# Need example of using Promise in node.js

Tags: node.js, promise

I need an example how to use promise in node.js. I have a variable connection that must be closed after a call to function finished. Here is the flow how my program should run

```
var connection = {
   /*create connection */
}

/* call to a function */

/* close connection after function finish */
connection.close();
```

Comment: read this article about promises: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/

Comment: `callToAFunction() . then(() => connection.close())`, assuming of course `callToAFunction` returns a promise.

Comment: I use `function (data) { console.log('done'); }` inside `.then`  but didn't work even in the function I have included `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){ })`

Comment: This question does not show any evidence of basic research on the topic.  Before coming here, you should do your own research, try some things, then tell us exactly where you got stuck and post what you tried.  We will help you figure out why what you tried did not work, but we are not really a from-scratch tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using bluebird (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

```
let con = undefined

Promise.try(() => createConnection()) // create connection
  .then(_con => {
     con = _con // assign connection

     // TO DO STUFF
  })
  .then(() => {
     con.close() // close connection
  })
  .catch(e => {
     // handle exception here
  })
```